# add effects for new line in html textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

currently I update my textarea with jquery:

```
$('#txtBox1').val($('#txtBox1').val()+ "\n# " + data.message[i]);
```

it queries a database and check for new lines and append them to the txtbox, the problem is if there are multiple new lines, its hard to distinguish them from the old lines.

is there any transitional effect in javascript or jquery? something like decaying color for the new text or pop up from the bottom like `show();` from jquery?

thx.

Comment: Not sure if this is of any use, you could try using a `contentEditable` div and wrap the new messages in <span> tags. That way you can use classes to style them dynamically whatever way you want when they are added.

Comment: May be your are looking for something like this 
http://dropthebit.com/580/fancy-input-jquery-plugin/

Comment: `textarea` can't have HTML, hence there is not a direct way to do this. You could use content editable `div` instead of `textarea`, or "higlight" the new text with a selection, or an extra partial transparent `div` over the text, create and combine several `textarea`s etc...

Comment: but i dont want the user editing the text, I guess i should use use a regular div and adding text to it?

Comment: @3v01 You could use `readonly` attribute, something like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJk47/).

Comment: @Teemu thats a good idea, but since i already changed my code using `div` instead of `textarea`, i want to try to see if its possible to do a fading color effect of the font, i will use urs as a backup plan, thx

Comment: @FaceOfJock oh man, dont know know but i missed ur comment, cool effects, i think i will try it, thx

Answer (score 0):

Into a basic textarea, I'm afraid it's not possible.

But you can use a div, that you make editable by using contentEditable. That way, you can handle every new line has a div or a span.

Take a look at this:

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: yea, i am trying using a `div` but probably not `contenteditable` since i dont want user to edit the text

Comment: Ho ok, so that is pretty easy. You can use jQuery to add a new line. Something like this : $('#container').append('<span style="display: none;">New line</span>'); $('#container > span:hidden').fadeIn(500);